# Тестовые письма на почте. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, cms

Такие сообщение(обратный звонок на сайте) приходят на почту каждый день, по 10-15 шт.

Name: 59b1495bb84a2 Tel: E-mail: csatrustegui@gmail.com

Name: 59afb372e278f Tel: E-mail: dhops02@gmail.com

. . .

Также они отображаются в админ панели.
Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с данной проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка проблема в том что боты сабмиттят в вашу форму обратной связи думая что это форма комментария (точнее не думая - просто сабмиттят и все). Причина - отсутствие защиты от спама.

Можете поставить какую либо CAPTCHA, или просто добавлять какое то поле через JS, а затем проверять его наличие на приемной стороне.